# Git status doesn't show files to be changed in fixup commit

Tags: git

I have a pre-commit hook that simply runs `flake8` on any changed files, along the lines of

```
#!/bin/bash
flake8 --config=flake8 $(git status -s | grep -E '\.py$' | cut -c 4-)
```

When I try to create a fixup commit with

```
git commit --no-gpg-sign --no-edit --fixup\=f673953437
```

the pre-commit hook is run on a slew of other files that don't show up with `git status -s` nor are they part of the commit that is the fixup target (f673953437). It's difficult to figure out where they are coming from and why they're showing up as part of the commit. Is there a way to get `git status` (or some other command) to show what is going to change for a fixup commit?

Comment: Is it possible you are testing your `$(git status -s | grep -E '\.py$' | cut -c 4-)` command from a different directory than from where your hook is run? (Maybe try printing a message from your hook with the output of that command.)

Comment: You may want to look into pre-commit.com (the site and the software found there), as the files that are scheduled to go into a new commit are not necessarily the files in the working tree. The pre-commit code handles all of this for you.